# How to sync app data when server add or update the record

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have developed an Android app which gets data from MySQL, but the problem is that when insert, update & delete happen so it loads all the data from server, and I want to sync only that record which is insert or update.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
            //Activity activity = (Activity)context;
            Log.d("st", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
            dataBaseHelper.createDataBase();
            dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //utils.getdata("Userid");
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
            Date date = new Date();
            String link = "http://ec2-52-4-106-227.compute-1.amazonaws.com/capalinoappaws/apis/getProcurementDaily.php?currentDate="+simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            link = link.replace(" ","%20");
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);

            Log.i("Response", "Response : " + response);
            if (!dataBaseHelper.sqliteDataBase.isOpen())
                dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
            dataBaseHelper.delete("ProcurementMaster");
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String ProcurementID = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementID");
                String ProcurementEPIN = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementEPIN");
                String ProcurementSource = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementSource");
                String ProcurementAgencyID = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementAgencyID");

                        /*ProcurementAgencyID = ProcurementAgencyID.replace(")","");
                        ProcurementAgencyID = ProcurementAgencyID.replace("(","");*/
                ProcurementAgencyID = ProcurementAgencyID.replace("'","\\u0027");

                String ProcurementTypeIDP = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementTypeIDP");
                String ProcurementTitle = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementTitle");
                //Log.d("ProcurementTitle",ProcurementTitle);
/*
                        ProcurementTitle = ProcurementTitle.replace(")","");
                        ProcurementTitle = ProcurementTitle.replace("(","");*/
                ProcurementTitle = ProcurementTitle.replace("'","''");

                String ProcurementShortDescription = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementShortDescription");

                        /*ProcurementShortDescription = ProcurementShortDescription.replace(")","");
                        ProcurementShortDescription = ProcurementShortDescription.replace("(","");*/
                ProcurementShortDescription = ProcurementShortDescription.replace("'","''");


                String ProcurementLongDescription = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementLongDescription");

                        /*ProcurementLongDescription = ProcurementLongDescription.replace(")","");
                        ProcurementLongDescription = ProcurementLongDescription.replace("(","");*/
                ProcurementLongDescription = ProcurementLongDescription.replace("'","''");

                String ProcurementProposalDeadline = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementProposalDeadline");
                String ProcurementPreConferenceDate = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementPreConferenceDate");
                String ProcurementQuestionDeadline = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementQuestionDeadline");
                String ProcurementAgencyURL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementAgencyURL");

                String ProcurementDocument1URL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementDocument1URL");
                String ProcurementDocument2URL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementDocument2URL");
                String ProcurementDocument3URL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementDocument3URL");
                String ProcurementDocument4URL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementDocument4URL");
                String ProcurementDocument5URL = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementDocument5URL");
                String ProcurementAddedDate = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementAddedDate");

                String ProcurementContractValueID = jsonobj.getString("ProcurementContractValueID");
                String Status = jsonobj.getString("Status");
                String LASTEDITEDUSERNAME = jsonobj.getString("LASTEDITEDUSERNAME");
                String PDFPath = jsonobj.getString("PDFPath");

                boolean isInserted = dataBaseHelper.InsertProcurementMaster(new ProcMaster(Integer.valueOf(ProcurementID), ProcurementEPIN, ProcurementSource,
                        ProcurementAgencyID, ProcurementTypeIDP, ProcurementTitle,ProcurementShortDescription,ProcurementLongDescription,ProcurementProposalDeadline,
                        ProcurementPreConferenceDate,ProcurementQuestionDeadline,ProcurementAgencyURL,ProcurementDocument1URL,ProcurementDocument2URL,ProcurementDocument3URL,
                        ProcurementDocument4URL,ProcurementDocument5URL,ProcurementAddedDate,ProcurementContractValueID,Status,LASTEDITEDUSERNAME,PDFPath));
                //Log.d("InsertProcurementMaster", "Inserted");

                //list_data.add(new ListData(image, contentShortDescription, ContentRelevantDateTime));

                //isinserted = dataBaseHelper.InsertUserProcurmentTracking(been);
            }

            Log.d("et", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));


        } catch (Exception e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }
}
```

Comment: Two way synchronization is too broad for stackoverflow's answer ...

Answer (score 0):

try implementing sockets on client and server side.
https://socket.io/

Comment: it will obviously not work without some message queue ... Why? client is offline(no data connection), data had changed on the server, socket.io will not send the data to the client as it is offline ... not mention about conflict resolving ...